# App crashes after installation in iOS10

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

After upgrading to iOS 10, my application is crashing when installing it via iTunes. It does not crash if installed directly from Xcode. Once the app is installed, as soon as I open the app it displays the splash screen and closes without giving any error.

I am using following softwares:

- Xcode V8
- Cordova V6.3.1
- iOS v10

following is the device log:

```
    Incident Identifier: EE32E4F2-DA31-4BB1-83F5-06BEDF6BA0AA
CrashReporter Key:   77be39a8a3d20bec0c7dc271ac081aed89f0616b
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Process:             coreduetd [88]
Path:                /usr/libexec/coreduetd
Identifier:          coreduetd
Version:             ???
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Unspecified
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           <none> [139]


Date/Time:           2016-10-03 13:36:21.1927 -0500
Launch Time:         2016-10-03 13:36:03.0775 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  8

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2b016c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2affdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2adcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2ab908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1da048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2278d4 CFRunLoopRun + 112
6   coreduetd                       0x00000001000f6ce0 0x1000c8000 + 191712
7   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018b1bc5b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: PLClientLoggingAdaptivePermissionWorkQueue
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2b016c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2affdc mach_msg + 72
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b19f87c _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 516
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b19fcc4 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply + 60
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x000000018b3d5fe0 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 196
5   PowerLog                        0x000000018e51a878 -[PLClientLogger xpcSendMessageWithReply:withClientID:withKey:withPayload:] + 232
6   PowerLog                        0x000000018e51ad74 __57-[PLClientLogger permissionForClientID:withKey:withType:]_block_invoke + 140
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b189200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b1891c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b197444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b18c9a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b19938c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b1990ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b3912c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cea88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b391188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cea88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b391188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2b016c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2affdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2adcec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c2ab908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018c1da048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a52b2fe8 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AVFAudio                        0x00000001a52d8f14 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 84
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b393860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b393770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000018b2cea88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b391188 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.coreduet.knowledge.deletion
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ad500a0 objc_retain + 16
1   CoreDuet                        0x0000000193932240 __62-[_CDSpotlightItemRecorder deleteKnowledgeEventsWithBundleID:]_block_invoke + 724
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b189200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b1891c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b197444 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 928
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b18c9a8 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 652
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b19938c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 572
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018b1990ec _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 124
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b3912c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000018b390db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000121d5cf60   x1: 0x00000001002a4a00   x2: 0x0000000121dc0ce0   x3: 0x0000000000000005
    x4: 0x0000000000000005   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000000000   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000001a1b072d8f1  x11: 0x0000000121dc1000
   x12: 0xfffffffffffff000  x13: 0x0000000121dc0000  x14: 0x0000000008884000  x15: 0x0000000000004000
   x16: 0x000000018b3046c8  x17: 0x000000018ad53014  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000192c6ebe6
   x20: 0x0000000121d89170  x21: 0x0000000121d89170  x22: 0x00000001b072d8f0  x23: 0x0000000121d64e20
   x24: 0x0000000121d5f430  x25: 0x0000000121d5f460  x26: 0x0000000121da7990  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000121d67bd0   fp: 0x000000016ea62cd0   lr: 0x0000000193932240
    sp: 0x000000016ea62c30   pc: 0x000000018ad500a0 cpsr: 0x20000000

Binary Images:
0x1000c8000 - 0x1001bffff coreduetd arm64  <879908a238be3c8b8eb0e2eefe1ba268> /usr/libexec/coreduetd
0x10021c000 - 0x10024bfff dyld arm64  <fc8715469f7b30228b67a5ae12cadf10> /usr/lib/dyld
0x102308000 - 0x102337fff DuetKnowledgeMonitor arm64  <49ec18a2d0a931bfba8aa4997a987cdb> /System/Library/DuetKnowledgeBase/Monitors/DuetKnowledgeMonitor.bundle/DuetKnowledgeMonitor
0x18acb4000 - 0x18acb5fff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <8788325e11bc31a39b075a3497d26ebd> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x18acb6000 - 0x18ad0bfff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <95f6dd603b933208ba95cc2d84613c54> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x18ad0c000 - 0x18ad2cfff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <286b3adc78d1308eaa0d6f10914b1fa7> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x18ad30000 - 0x18b109fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <56adf6a5a61b3ef1968bae3dd66e4893> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x18b10a000 - 0x18b10efff libcache.dylib arm64  <4073ffab5dee3540b91e3ea1292d4944> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x18b10f000 - 0x18b11afff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <cbc60c6bf6843b489a4d4b47bc9caba8> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x18b11b000 - 0x18b11efff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <6b7d58fa13473277aae76d339b13a724> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x18b11f000 - 0x18b126fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <2130e1083c2b31498e4873b42c01a87c> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x18b127000 - 0x18b187fff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <69592d5de33d337baf0746846b8e8b71> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x18b188000 - 0x18b1b7fff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <9da4900c6d953655bbfcc6b31c990e9c> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x18b1b8000 - 0x18b1bcfff libdyld.dylib arm64  <b69bc0979de93e7c9cac9d89b284039f> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x18b1bd000 - 0x18b1bdfff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <7e180d7e5df13f699dbc6bb79ad46116> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x18b1be000 - 0x18b1c3fff libmacho.dylib arm64  <40cb3d5ba75831cdac02a56cab260364> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x18b1c4000 - 0x18b1c5fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <58f887789b983f71a5cfd5777958da77> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x18b1c6000 - 0x18b1ddfff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <2ec01cd41fa73c94b3f0ba16aacd3858> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x18b1de000 - 0x18b1defff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <e49693e120c33ee580a602e909c83abe> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x18b1df000 - 0x18b25dfff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <051c0135e5d835979ce0166c05c8f381> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x18b25e000 - 0x18b262fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <c253d3f37bac39bcb755bd85f8c6b7fd> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x18b263000 - 0x18b268fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <a845710abeb9350596b19219de14752d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x18b269000 - 0x18b26afff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <e10d8ff725fe3a88a5328b24666b4d34> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18b26b000 - 0x18b283fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <23df3c03932932869f59404b025c3153> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x18b284000 - 0x18b28afff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <441464753206379bafd15b113907f608> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x18b28b000 - 0x18b2aefff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <2e66f9d1ee0837ff895155dd12b2c956> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x18b2af000 - 0x18b2d3fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <04e6664af08030e1ad7d9f2249e47e18> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x18b2d4000 - 0x18b300fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <786e37b9fc8431f5bfb79550eed0c3ce> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x18b301000 - 0x18b31cfff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <6eef211324863711a1d99713c51512cb> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x18b31d000 - 0x18b373fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <84d56a9d88ba32f9830d884a7aa14c3b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x18b374000 - 0x18b37dfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <a8d963518d643327ac1991dbf8f15f91> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x18b37e000 - 0x18b388fff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <abb481f869e83db39d0ee3e61a9c0554> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18b389000 - 0x18b38ffff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <6735814899ed328499ce8a0f59ff49b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x18b390000 - 0x18b399fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <be17c5de3ff83a8695913479341c34ec> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x18b39a000 - 0x18b39dfff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <f269179060d53feaaac004e7c838b44d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x18b39e000 - 0x18b3a5fff libsystem_symptoms.dylib arm64  <2e6f3a69a33a3a309ca86ef8358c2b55> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib
0x18b3a6000 - 0x18b3c7fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <3ed1ebdc2ed435dc87973ddbf563744b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x18b3c8000 - 0x18b3cdfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <8e51acc655103210bcd8c557e4f103ab> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x18b3ce000 - 0x18b3cefff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <abee403ad3fe3b428af3d4ed901a2dfc> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x18b3cf000 - 0x18b3f5fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <9bbf09cd8cfd3f94bae40fac797416e0> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x18b3f6000 - 0x18b610fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <49bff0b83e023804af2b53d77d1f6cb4> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x18b611000 - 0x18b621fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <5e67d9e80348304187cd8bf557849015> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x18c1d1000 - 0x18c554fff CoreFoundation arm64  <c4824900d70e3fd5b01dbb079b63eae1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x18c555000 - 0x18c565fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <f3a3eb26182839e0ac4646d0e2f9e9c4> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x18c566000 - 0x18c566fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <2cfdece2a96330968c249f7d9e7811ad> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x18c567000 - 0x18c5e1fff IOKit arm64  <27c8e5eb76843818abd4a0b0d5dfccc3> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x18c5e2000 - 0x18c602fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <f8456dbddfbb35d29491c29b43860e6f> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x18c603000 - 0x18c6edfff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <edc3ce1ed39b39fd9c3c535d9e542967> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x18c6ee000 - 0x18c77afff Security arm64  <624164bf18ba32c8a7f28b5031ef6aa5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x18c77b000 - 0x18c7e5fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <486dd4e417a83cc6a09e0b7de9319356> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x18c7e6000 - 0x18c8fafff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <511215637edc3a0f8d3416fe4536881d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x18c8fb000 - 0x18cc6afff CFNetwork arm64  <ca09941bfd353bb8b6b679a0f14cad1e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x18cc6b000 - 0x18cc7bfff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <b312e3b393893c0db8f793f370dae319> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x18cc7c000 - 0x18cc94fff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <3c157ec9f2e83f99a26f322feb7deabc> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x18cc95000 - 0x18ccaffff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <af22ff8591193afa81d6d044c5cd7978> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x18ccb0000 - 0x18ccd9fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <1e4278f3e3323387ac5c90f975232c07> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x18ccda000 - 0x18ccdbfff liblangid.dylib arm64  <c2cccb75f84e3b8a9c2ce6e32e812eb9> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x18ccdc000 - 0x18cfaafff Foundation arm64  <a6ad10553017396ebb4eba2a4ad331d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x18cfab000 - 0x18d057fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <499c291219e730d79cf409daee75db9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x18d058000 - 0x18d39afff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <f07da3926d4a3fb0bfcbe3b3b026b54f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x18d39b000 - 0x18d63dfff vImage arm64  <c3827fd6a2763bb9bf22e65906eb3cfc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x18d63e000 - 0x18d660fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <bd641d6b451430a8a26dde179a9bfc4a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x18d661000 - 0x18d675fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <e9a40ae4066c3d3ebab7aec269c6f69e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x18d676000 - 0x18d687fff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <66e35a109b573fe98941afd7e9921214> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x18d688000 - 0x18d700fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <c2ce3490f1b633119d556081ffd0caa0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x18d701000 - 0x18d701fff vecLib arm64  <c07ed4a995bd35a89bea45c4fd101553> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x18d702000 - 0x18d702fff Accelerate arm64  <5057f428ad8539a9b13b2a607bc7839f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x18d703000 - 0x18dc50fff CoreGraphics arm64  <4a137515f15e30a495edf7ec114755e0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x18dc51000 - 0x18dc65fff GraphicsServices arm64  <1e0ed9315f4830088aa2086205f45050> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x18dc66000 - 0x18dcb1fff AppSupport arm64  <1fd5606d67de38b484c8e09e0783b4af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x18dcb2000 - 0x18ddd2fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <37baec08da073e729066bded8c9b53da> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18ddd3000 - 0x18de29fff BaseBoard arm64  <160dad81a8de3c5cb46f17c3d4eb7b87> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x18de2a000 - 0x18de35fff AssertionServices arm64  <3fac49b1df4c373184edb6af5d3a09dd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x18de36000 - 0x18de62fff BackBoardServices arm64  <b531352894cd36bbbb6d0b9d503566a7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x18de67000 - 0x18deb6fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <af1172067ff2304d9d3c8a2f92f04255> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x18deba000 - 0x18def0fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <b575c6c21a493b4a87e2dd05bb8cf02a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x18def1000 - 0x18df08fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <734ebf66412c3aa5ac99334f29ebe620> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x18df09000 - 0x18df11fff IOSurface arm64  <0c687f05288f30efbb936e54be9a6f58> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x18df12000 - 0x18df1dfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <12947e09f9ca3245ae33ede73e0b651f> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x18df1e000 - 0x18df33fff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <b17ade4774223014893f614b1d14de61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x18df34000 - 0x18df36fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <969c522dc6183cb8ada7073b07353512> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x18df37000 - 0x18df77fff AppleJPEG arm64  <ddac80f526a73d5684ad96a7faeac161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x18df78000 - 0x18e507fff ImageIO arm64  <0cc6da0a6265372190bd34b428c02a9f> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x18e508000 - 0x18e50efff TCC arm64  <fca78b84e3f73fdc90b9d1e5d5ff6919> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x18e50f000 - 0x18e513fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <621603daf2bf3e7ab75aafd59f095c5b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x18e514000 - 0x18e520fff PowerLog arm64  <c2cd0fdbbf6e385ba55748201f88a7a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x18e521000 - 0x18e589fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <1af42608ce2b3f4ebcee64dcdbac02b6> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x18e58a000 - 0x18e59cfff CommonUtilities arm64  <0098d095d66733988b5a6e73803f37a6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x18e59d000 - 0x18e5b1fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <b04eddd5ef0839a6aee2707f5c14aa1a> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x18e5b2000 - 0x18e84cfff CoreData arm64  <65f30a82a6683482bbdb857c83f3fc56> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x18e84d000 - 0x18e850fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <ef615871768f3db8b7f860b5fd7bf707> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x18e851000 - 0x18e856fff IOAccelerator arm64  <d7135a13f4753c9eb8b4b79455175d32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x18e857000 - 0x18e858fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <a5694c66e17b346ca36396fd40029618> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x18e859000 - 0x18e85cfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <7d0b5c6277ea362598ea9c06f292eaa0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x18e85d000 - 0x18e8a0fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <679d74c254e13f1c925f38b82d8e6963> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x18e8a1000 - 0x18e8abfff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <402e4f5820f834f5807f5fa448902f2c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x18e8ac000 - 0x18e8b3fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <c913022952a1394a928f7bbf5bfec3e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x18e8b4000 - 0x18e8b4fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <fd7029ad82583e1f89ca3a1ddff84df2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x18e8b5000 - 0x18e912fff Metal arm64  <18991406aed530c99a3dcca4ca4371b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x18e913000 - 0x18e91dfff OpenGLES arm64  <48579b12ba843baf8688c929e4aa1350> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x18e91e000 - 0x18e942fff CoreVideo arm64  <865a7204d95b3117bf535727201a1da9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x18e943000 - 0x18e945fff OAuth arm64  <f202cfb14ee333f1a7502e5a75f2df92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x18e946000 - 0x18e984fff Accounts arm64  <79664bb249ab30799fdce891cf8a91cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x18e985000 - 0x18ea77fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <bf0bd341bdd43ec7bd40d067233e57a8> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x18ea78000 - 0x18ebc3fff CoreAudio arm64  <0a134f19c9ae39b79dcdd8af00189b56> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x18ebc4000 - 0x18ebc7fff UserFS arm64  <c0a53a908768398cb07c22ec2ff1abb2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x18ebc8000 - 0x18ecd2fff CoreMedia arm64  <d0cc03900e45378e98d8193662edf565> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x18ecd3000 - 0x18ecd9fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <0680676b2f97349fb5742ec91e20f429> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x18ecda000 - 0x18ed66fff CoreTelephony arm64  <f6ab69bda98d3b619d2b41a57fc2c69e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x18ed67000 - 0x18ee71fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <7a8928d14bd538b29f9c8d2be8fb889a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x18ee72000 - 0x18ef01fff VideoToolbox arm64  <63305fbde9b03b7891bb48b8868f4f36> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x18ef02000 - 0x18ef02fff FontServices arm64  <c6d2054d8d013dbdafecea3ad8948d76> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x18ef03000 - 0x18f04ffff CoreText arm64  <89e2f40a358a3760885d80ebb4491ac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x18f050000 - 0x18f06afff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <84a84046c997386b891fff8f4c249d20> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x18f06b000 - 0x18f093fff PersistentConnection arm64  <46122ee81ebc3ae0a60ae25c730a129e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x18f094000 - 0x18f09afff DataMigration arm64  <0aa788c904ca304ea9a9bf19ee990b53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x18f09b000 - 0x18f4f1fff AudioToolbox arm64  <f1ac89ed6113395bb6f8d9eef1b345dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x18f4f2000 - 0x18f6c9fff QuartzCore arm64  <dfdc0c40cf153854b84a6bc06b12b4ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x18f6ca000 - 0x18f6d0fff Netrb arm64  <019a8ba8af39378891e3689409db009d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x18f6e2000 - 0x18f702fff libmis.dylib arm64  <039e7c4ab2c53597ba3403fc0b5516e3> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x18f7f5000 - 0x18f8dafff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <083f833136993b47bee913c927ee65de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x18f9c3000 - 0x18f9cdfff MediaAccessibility arm64  <4cdf6c8a21143e04838c8985ca3ab8a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x18f9ce000 - 0x18f9defff MobileAsset arm64  <0c5fb05c798b3a8cabbace58bc7b0ec1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x18f9df000 - 0x18fa50fff ColorSync arm64  <5762d9f6aa723c5f9ac4faf32c313791> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x18fa51000 - 0x18fac0fff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <5d6f9961367c3336a19b5283176262df> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x18fac1000 - 0x18fef0fff FaceCore arm64  <c6528cdf6e1d3fe48f12735bbc8fe99f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x18fef1000 - 0x18ff6cfff Quagga arm64  <9f220dabf92e372bb1851251b1f66fe1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x18ff6d000 - 0x190136fff CoreImage arm64  <0a9f9730278e31e19e59bdcabfcb6ff1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x192ec0000 - 0x192ee8fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <13fb911b0abc3dbe8b3d431b7a59b4b9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x192ee9000 - 0x192f0efff DataAccessExpress arm64  <5799a178384d3ce28527b23c720ed04c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x192f0f000 - 0x192f30fff NetworkStatistics arm64  <fbdf2cf4373d305584bdf54398fd5613> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x192f31000 - 0x192fb9fff AddressBook arm64  <b835a0db2c4b3b42bcc3d7487fd67ed8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x192fba000 - 0x1930eefff CoreMotion arm64  <b4fe074374f13922aaa6833f2278495e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x1930ef000 - 0x19311cfff CacheDelete arm64  <93e649608229314ab93d03dc37330685> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CacheDelete.framework/CacheDelete
```

Comment: Can you upload the device log (from Xcode > Windows > Devices) for review?

Comment: @TyLy..updated the question with the logs...though I don't see any logs which are specific to my app.

Comment: It looks like the crash is at Thread 8:
<pre>
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018ad500a0 objc_retain + 16
1   CoreDuet                        0x0000000193932240 __62-[_CDSpotlightItemRecorder deleteKnowledgeEventsWithBundleID:]_block_invoke + 724
</pre>
Are you using the JaviSoto library?   Can you try to install the same .ipa that you've built with the distribution profile via iTune onto your device?  Does it work or still crash?  If it still crashes, then it is not related to App Center.

Comment: its crashing with the iTunes also..? can you guess what could be the issue?

Comment: I am getting crash log with exact same trigger: `[_CDSpotlightItemRecorder deleteKnowledgeEventsWithBundleID:]_block_invoke + 724` Did you figure out what's going on? But mime one crashed with Xcode dev build and I need to perform multiple steps to trigger it.

Comment: Are you using Cordova or is it a native app?

Comment: It is hybrid app using WKWebView